# How can I handle the Angular (click) event for the middle mouse button?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an icon that acts as a link to open an URL. When a user clicks on that link I need to make an API call and some other actions.

Now clicking with the left button aswell as Ctrl + Click triggers the method fine. Only when opening the link with the middle mouse click, the method gets not fired.

```
<a [href]="'somelink.com' + someVariable" target="_blank" (click)="someMethod('some', 'params')">
    <div class="some-icon">
        <img src="/assets/icon/icon.svg" height="54" alt="Icon" />
    </div>
</a>
```

Is there another way to call a method in my Component on middle click?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For secondary mouse buttons, you can handle the [auxclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event) event. In the following example, the `click` event is triggered by the primary mouse button, and the `auxclick` event is triggered by the other mouse buttons.

```
<a (click)="onClick($event)" (auxclick)="onAuxClick($event)">...</a>
```

```
onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  console.log("click - button", event.button, event.which);
}

onAuxClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  console.log("auxclick - button", event.button, event.which);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnkmzr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo. Please note that the same method can handle both events. I call different methods in the demo to show which event is handled.

Comment: Spent hours trying to stop behavior of middle click on <a> tags, finally found this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which

and this is the implemention

```
(click)="$event.which == 2 ? yourFunction($event) : $event.preventDefault()"
```

preventDefault() is used to stop the event.

Comment: I have tried this. But it doesn't fire the event at all.

Comment: @Thimo as you can read in the link this is not a standard feature. Do you have already tried with another browser?

Comment: Yes I have tried it in Chrome and Firefox. (auxclick)="someFunction()" is what seems to work thanks.

Comment: In angular 9 at least, the handler (click) only handles normal clicks, not the auxiliar of middle